# Prestashop 1.6 automatically apply specific discount per product, no coupon

Tags: product, cart, prestashop-1.6, price, discount

I need to apply some specific discount in some specific products automatically in the cart.

To make it more clear, instead of having the price fixed and baked with the product, because of some marketing problems, I need to keep the original price of some specific products and then apply the discount in the cart. But because of that I need it to be automatically added so no customer will skip or miss it. Therefore, I don't want to make it with a coupon because the customer needs to know or see it and add the coupon to the order.

About the products and the discount, I want to do it in some specific products and apply the discount (amount not percent) for each of these products, for instance if it is -5 euros per product if one customer add 2 of those products to the cart he is going to get -10 euros of total discount.

Any ideas? I'm using Prestashop 1.6.

Thank you in advance,
George

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved pretty easy.

Just create your cart rule(s) binded to desired products with an empty coupon value,
they will be applied automatically on checkout.

Comment: I tried that but the coupon was only suggested in the cart not automatically added. I don’t want the customer to do anything. Except if I did something wrong. I’m totally newbie to it

Comment: You DO NOT have to enable the Highlight option, just leave the coupon code field empty and it will be applied during "add to cart" as longs as it match the cart rule requirements.

Comment: That’s what I did first but it was not added automatically. However, I will check it out again just in case I missed something. Thank you very much!

Comment: I tried it and it worked, so as it seems I did something wrong the first time. Anyway, it seems to work just fine except a small detail. I want to add the discount for piece of each product again, for instance if someone buys 2 pieces I want two times discount as well. Right now it doesn't do that. It only applies the discount 1 time nomatter how many pieces of the same product I add to the cart. Do you know if this is possible? Thank you again!